# Why does gcc reject `new v < new v` when `v` is not a template?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

Simple test case:

```
#include <iostream>
struct v {};
int main() {
    std::cout << __VERSION__ << '\n' << (new v < new v) << '\n';
}
```

I'm aware that comparing the pointers has an unspecified result, but that's not relevant here (and a similar example could be produced with some more keystrokes, as in the later coliru snippets).

The C++ standard I have handy says, in §14.2 paragraph 3:

> After name lookup finds that a name is a *template-name* or that an *operator-function-id* or a *literal-operator-id* refers to a set of overloaded functions any member of which is a function template, if this is followed by a <kbd><</kbd>, the <kbd><</kbd> is always taken as the delimiter of a *template-argument-list* and never as the less-than operator.

Since `v` is neither a template name nor a function id, I don't see why this should apply. And neither, apparently, does [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d1ba227e1eaba2c):

```
4.2.1 Compatible Clang 3.8.0 (tags/RELEASE_380/final 263969)
1
```

However, [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c743c16b7fd6696) (6.3.0) complains:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:4:46: error: 'v' is not a template
     std::cout << __VERSION__ << '\n' << (new v < new v) << '\n';
                                              ^
```

Am I (and clang) missing something here?

Versions without unspecified behaviour: [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c59287b0e8c102a4) [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/830cb4afe767877b)

Version with minus operator instead of less than: [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e87adde760011f1c) (no compilation error)

---

#### Addendum

Gcc does not have the same problem with functions; with [template functions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/016d2b2616fba204) it insists that the <kbd><</kbd> must be a template argument delimiter, but not with [non-template functions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4604d92f45fa4a63). That adds weight to the argument that it's a bug, so I filed it as [Bug 79192](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79192).

---

#### Note:

In case anyone is curious, this came up while I was trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785372/shift-reduce-conflict-in-bison-when-trying-to-add-optional-rule), where the questioner was writing a grammar for a vaguely C++-like language and stumbled on the above ambiguity. I wanted to explain the solution used by C++, but the discrepancy between the two compilers made it difficult.

Comment: I suggest filing a bug against gcc. Most likely the developers will agree that it is a bug, but if they do not, then they will tell you why they think they are right.

Comment: Your GCC version has a bunch of `*`s where the other version didn't. Why the difference?

Comment: @user2357112: I made versions with dereferences and a definition of operator< to avoid the unspecified behaviour, but I agree that was confusing. I reverted both snippets to the one in the OP, leaving the specified-behaviour snippets as well for your viewing pleasure. Either way, the parsing question is the same.

Comment: Looks like an erroneous parse error to me. I don't know the ins and outs of the "new" `<>` parsing rules (as of C++11) but I'd expect this to work as-is.

Comment: Anyway I agree with Brian.

Comment: writing given line as `std::cout << __VERSION__ << '\n' << ( (new v) < (new v) ) << '\n';`  seems to be workaround for this error

Comment: @Anty: Yes, I'm completely aware of that. Also, the expression would be a syntax error were `v` a template name or one of the other possibilities listed in the quoted standard section, and then you would definitely need parentheses. In any case, the expression is nonsensical, and it's hard (though not impossible) to imagine a context in which is makes any sort of sense. None of that is relevant to my question, which is whether there is some other clause of the standard which neither I nor clang is aware of which would cause the `<` to be parsed as a template-argument-list delimiter.

Comment: @rici You can further reduce the example to `int main() { new int < new int; }`. No header, no struct, no stream, same error.

Comment: @rici Note also that `int main() { new int{} < new int; }` works just fine. It seems GCC misinterpreted the invokation of `new` in the first case.

Comment: @skypjack: GCC is misinterpreting the `<` as a template argument delimiter. If `v`  could take template arguments, that interpretation would be required (see the quote). There are various  ways to remove that possible interpretation: `(new v)`, `new (v)`, `new v()`, or even an explicitly empty template argument list `new v<>`. But `v` is not a template, so the `<` cannot be a template argument delimiter, and my opinion is that GCC should interpret it as a less-than operator. The question is whether that opinion is correct or whether the standard allows or requires the behaviour of GCC.

Comment: @rici I agree that the opinion is right, but the reduced example that uses `int`s (see my comment above) is even a more meaningful example that doesn't require to include `iostream` or define any custom class.

Comment: @Brian: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79192

Comment: I think this is it, in the GCC code's parser.c: `/* There is no valid C++ program where a non-template type is
  followed by a "<".  That usually indicates that the user thought
  that the type was a template.  */`

Comment: @johannes nice find. But is the comment correct? I believe my program, at least the one with the dereferencing, is valid (if not very useful). Am I wrong?

Comment: Not only in your example, but also with `&Foo::operator v < something`, we have a situation that could occur in a valid program. In fact, GCC fails on it aswell: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f35c1aa5b3f9832d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug, or at least the bug report was accepted by the GCC maintainers.

In a comment, Johannes Schaub-litb pointed out that the code which rejects this construct is at line 16781 of `cp/parser.c`:

```
  /* There is no valid C++ program where a non-template type is
 followed by a "<".  That usually indicates that the user thought
 that the type was a template.  */
  cp_parser_check_for_invalid_template_id (parser, type, none_type,
                       token->location);
```

and that the comment is incorrect, since the check also rejects other valid programs such as

```
struct A {
   operator A();  
};

void operator<(A (A::*)(), A);

int main() {
   &A::operator A < A();   
}
```

([on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f35c1aa5b3f9832d))